# Connection not releasing for StoredProcedureQuery without @Transactional

Tags: jpa, spring-data, eclipselink

I have the following service which simply logs an error message to the database.  When I do not have `@Transactional` on the method, the connection stays active until all the connections are used up.  All the `StoredProcedureQuery` calls that return a result do not have this problem.

Why do I need to mark the method as `@Transactional` to have it release the connection?

```
@Service
public class SSOErrorLogServiceImpl implements SSOErrorLogService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void logError(String errorMessage, String request){
        StoredProcedureQuery proc =   em.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("dbo.spSSOLogError");
        proc.setParameter("errorMessage", errorMessage);
        proc.setParameter("request", request);
        proc.execute();
    }
}
```

DataConfig

```
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory
            = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

    entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(reflexDataSource());
    entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.company.platform.jpa");
    entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());

    Properties additionalProperties = new Properties();
    additionalProperties.put("eclipselink.weaving", "false");

    entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties);

    return entityManagerFactory;
}

@Bean
public HikariDataSource reflexDataSource() {
    HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();

    dataSource.setLeakDetectionThreshold(20000);
    dataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(20);
    dataSource.setConnectionTimeout(5000);
    dataSource.setRegisterMbeans(false);
    dataSource.setInitializationFailFast(false);
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(driver);
    dataSource.setJdbcUrl(url);
    dataSource.setUsername(user);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);
    return dataSource;
}
```

Logs without transaction (excerpt)

```
[EL Finer]: connection: 2016-09-30 14:33:16.955--ServerSession(317574415)--Thread(Thread[Test worker,5,main])--client acquired: 1151058631
[EL Finer]: transaction: 2016-09-30 14:33:16.962--ClientSession(1151058631)--Thread(Thread[Test worker,5,main])--acquire unit of work: 544160013
[EL Finest]: query: 2016-09-30 14:33:16.962--UnitOfWork(544160013)--Thread(Thread[Test worker,5,main])--Execute query ResultSetMappingQuery(name="dbo.spSSOLogError" )
[EL Finest]: connection: 2016-09-30 14:33:16.963--ServerSession(317574415)--Connection(1107704332)--Thread(Thread[Test worker,5,main])--Connection acquired from connection pool [read].
[EL Finest]: connection: 2016-09-30 14:33:16.963--ServerSession(317574415)--Thread(Thread[Test worker,5,main])--reconnecting to external connection pool
[EL Fine]: sql: 2016-09-30 14:33:16.963--ServerSession(317574415)--Connection(539538496)--Thread(Thread[Test worker,5,main])--EXECUTE dbo.spSSOLogError @errorMessage = ?, @request = ?
    bind => [Message, Request]
2016-09-30 14:33:16,984 | TRACE | org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager:394 - afterTestMethod(): instance [com.somecompany.platform.jpa.ssoerrorlog.SSOErrorLogServiceTest@314c32e8], method [public void com.somecompany.platform.jpa.ssoerrorlog.SSOErrorLogServiceTest.test_logError()], exception [null]
2016-09-30 14:33:16,985 | DEBUG | org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener:94 - After test method: context [DefaultTestContext@6cce3af3 testClass = SSOErrorLogServiceTest, testInstance = com.somecompany.platform.jpa.ssoerrorlog.SSOErrorLogServiceTest@314c32e8, testMethod = test_logError@SSOErrorLogServiceTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@37770c96 testClass = SSOErrorLogServiceTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.somecompany.platform.jpa.ssoerrorlog.SSOErrorLogServiceTest$Config}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]], class dirties context [false], class mode [null], method dirties context [false].
2016-09-30 14:33:16,985 | TRACE | org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager:437 - afterTestClass(): class [class com.somecompany.platform.jpa.ssoerrorlog.SSOErrorLogServiceTest]
2016-09-30 14:33:16,986 | DEBUG | org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener:126 - After test class: context [DefaultTestContext@6cce3af3 testClass = SSOErrorLogServiceTest, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@37770c96 testClass = SSOErrorLogServiceTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.somecompany.platform.jpa.ssoerrorlog.SSOErrorLogServiceTest$Config}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]], dirtiesContext [false].
```

Logs with @Transaction

```
[EL Finer]: transaction: 2016-09-30 14:30:50.747--UnitOfWork(1448667590)--Thread(Thread[Test worker,5,main])--begin unit of work flush
[EL Finer]: transaction: 2016-09-30 14:30:50.747--UnitOfWork(1448667590)--Thread(Thread[Test worker,5,main])--end unit of work flush
[EL Finest]: query: 2016-09-30 14:30:50.747--UnitOfWork(1448667590)--Thread(Thread[Test worker,5,main])--Execute query ResultSetMappingQuery(name="dbo.spSSOLogError" )
[EL Finest]: connection: 2016-09-30 14:30:50.748--ServerSession(1432568628)--Connection(708660831)--Thread(Thread[Test worker,5,main])--Connection acquired from connection pool [default].
[EL Finer]: transaction: 2016-09-30 14:30:50.748--ClientSession(287210054)--Connection(708660831)--Thread(Thread[Test worker,5,main])--begin transaction
[EL Finest]: connection: 2016-09-30 14:30:50.748--ClientSession(287210054)--Thread(Thread[Test worker,5,main])--reconnecting to external connection pool
[EL Fine]: sql: 2016-09-30 14:30:50.75--ClientSession(287210054)--Connection(29007067)--Thread(Thread[Test worker,5,main])--EXECUTE dbo.spSSOLogError @errorMessage = ?, @request = ?
    bind => [Message, Request]
2016-09-30 14:30:50,772 | TRACE | org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport:519 - Completing transaction for [com.somecompany.platform.jpa.ssoerrorlog.SSOErrorLogServiceImpl.logError]
2016-09-30 14:30:50,772 | TRACE | org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager:926 - Triggering beforeCommit synchronization
2016-09-30 14:30:50,772 | TRACE | org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager:939 - Triggering beforeCompletion synchronization
2016-09-30 14:30:50,772 | DEBUG | org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager:755 - Initiating transaction commit
2016-09-30 14:30:50,773 | DEBUG | org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager:512 - Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl@8f90fd5]
[EL Finer]: transaction: 2016-09-30 14:30:50.773--UnitOfWork(1448667590)--Thread(Thread[Test worker,5,main])--begin unit of work commit
[EL Finer]: transaction: 2016-09-30 14:30:50.773--ClientSession(287210054)--Connection(29007067)--Thread(Thread[Test worker,5,main])--commit transaction
[EL Finest]: connection: 2016-09-30 14:30:50.775--ServerSession(1432568628)--Connection(708660831)--Thread(Thread[Test worker,5,main])--Connection released to connection pool [default].
[EL Finer]: transaction: 2016-09-30 14:30:50.775--UnitOfWork(1448667590)--Thread(Thread[Test worker,5,main])--end unit of work commit
[EL Finer]: transaction: 2016-09-30 14:30:50.775--UnitOfWork(1448667590)--Thread(Thread[Test worker,5,main])--resume unit of work
2016-09-30 14:30:50,775 | TRACE | org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager:952 - Triggering afterCommit synchronization
2016-09-30 14:30:50,775 | TRACE | org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager:968 - Triggering afterCompletion synchronization
2016-09-30 14:30:50,775 | TRACE | org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager:331 - Clearing transaction synchronization
2016-09-30 14:30:50,776 | TRACE | org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager:243 - Removed value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@4569d6c9] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@33d8b566] from thread [Test worker]
2016-09-30 14:30:50,776 | TRACE | org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager:243 - Removed value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@53d1206a] for key [JDBC URL = jdbc:sqlserver://somehost:1433;databaseName=Database, Username = test, partitions = 1, max (per partition) = 10, min (per partition) = 0, idle max age = 60 min, idle test period = 240 min, strategy = DEFAULT] from thread [Test worker]
2016-09-30 14:30:50,776 | DEBUG | org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager:600 - Closing JPA EntityManager [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl@8f90fd5] after transaction
2016-09-30 14:30:50,776 | DEBUG | org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils:432 - Closing JPA EntityManager
[EL Finer]: transaction: 2016-09-30 14:30:50.776--UnitOfWork(1448667590)--Thread(Thread[Test worker,5,main])--release unit of work
[EL Finer]: connection: 2016-09-30 14:30:50.776--ClientSession(287210054)--Thread(Thread[Test worker,5,main])--client released
2016-09-30 14:30:50,776 | TRACE | org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager:394 - afterTestMethod(): instance [com.somecompany.platform.jpa.ssoerrorlog.SSOErrorLogServiceTest@314c32e8], method [public void com.somecompany.platform.jpa.ssoerrorlog.SSOErrorLogServiceTest.test_logError()], exception [null]
2016-09-30 14:30:50,777 | DEBUG | org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener:94 - After test method: context [DefaultTestContext@6cce3af3 testClass = SSOErrorLogServiceTest, testInstance = com.somecompany.platform.jpa.ssoerrorlog.SSOErrorLogServiceTest@314c32e8, testMethod = test_logError@SSOErrorLogServiceTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@37770c96 testClass = SSOErrorLogServiceTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.somecompany.platform.jpa.ssoerrorlog.SSOErrorLogServiceTest$Config}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]], class dirties context [false], class mode [null], method dirties context [false].
2016-09-30 14:30:50,777 | TRACE | org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager:437 - afterTestClass(): class [class com.somecompany.platform.jpa.ssoerrorlog.SSOErrorLogServiceTest]
2016-09-30 14:30:50,778 | DEBUG | org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener:126 - After test class: context [DefaultTestContext@6cce3af3 testClass = SSOErrorLogServiceTest, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@37770c96 testClass = SSOErrorLogServiceTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.somecompany.platform.jpa.ssoerrorlog.SSOErrorLogServiceTest$Config}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]], dirtiesContext [false].
```

Comment: How have you specified the datasource, could it have a connection reuse limit?  366102 mentions something similar, but I previously under the impression the code was closing all connections in finally blocks.  Can you enable debugging that prints off where the stack the errant connections were obtained from?  Some servers are able to handle it, but I don't know if it is an option in your setup.

Comment: I don't think it's the reuse limit because the very first connection does not get released when I run it in a test.  By setting the leak detection threshold on the datasource, I can see pretty quickly in the log output which connections are not being released, but have not been able to get any output that may indicate why.  I assume it's because the SP is inserting data and needs the @Transaction in order to commit.

Comment: If there is no outer transaction, it should auto commit and get released.  Set logging to finest and see what might be being logged.

Comment: It's clear from the logs that the connection is not being released without the @Transactional, but as you said, I would expect it to auto commit and be released.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try changing `@PersistenceContext` to `@PersistanceUnit?`

EntityManagers obtained via `@PersistenceContext` are Container Managed Entity Manager as the container will be responsible for managing **"Entity Manager"** while EntityManagers obtained via `@PersistenceUnit / entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager()` are Application Managed Entity Manager and developer has to manage certain things in code (for e.g. releasing the resources acquired by EntityManager).

Answer (score 2):

Try release the query.

```
query.unwrap(ProcedureOutputs.class).release();
```

Answer (score 2):

We were facing the same issue with the `execute()` call. The connection was not getting closed. Looking at the code made it more clear: [execute()](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipselink.runtime/blob/master/jpa/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa/src/org/eclipse/persistence/internal/jpa/StoredProcedureQueryImpl.java#L317)

Calling the [executeUpdate()](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipselink.runtime/blob/master/jpa/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa/src/org/eclipse/persistence/internal/jpa/StoredProcedureQueryImpl.java#L400) solved it.